# SSL verses Encrypted Socket

Tags: c++, sockets, encryption, openssl

I am building an open source client/server app, what I am not sure about is what to use, SSL (e.g. OpenSSL) or encrypted packets over plain sockets.

I guess I have a few questions:

- Is there any security implications using encrypted packets over plain sockets?
- Is there any 'suggested' setups?  I know for a fact that OpenSSL has something like 1/2 million lines of code and had a lot of security issues.
- Is there any features that (Open)SSL give me that would a) beneficial or b) detrimental.

Hopefully this question has be structured in such a way that it will pass moderators :)

Comment: OpenSSL (well, SSL and TLS in general) does authentication as well as encryption. Without authentication, you're subject to man-in-the-middle attacks, for only one obvious example.

Comment: Ah thank you, my experience with this is limited.

Comment: *...my experience with this is limited..."* - Just [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/), but... You should probably avoid architecting and designing this yourself. If possible, switch to an IKEv2 or IPSec VPN (and ***not*** PPTP VPN or the others). In-app VPN has benefits over TLS. If you don't know what the benefits are, then you should probably avoid architecting and designing this yourself :) TLS is an OK choice. There's lots of landmines in TLS, so you can't just use it "as-is". You need to harden it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any security implications using encrypted packets over plain sockets?

Not if done correctly. BTW, SSL/TLS is encrypted packets over plain sockets.

> Is there any 'suggested' setups? I know for a fact that OpenSSL has something like 1/2 million lines of code and had a lot of security issues.

The suggested setup is to use code and algorithms which are known to be good. In no case you should invent your own, especially if you don't know much about the topic.

> Is there any features that (Open)SSL give me that would a) beneficial or b) detrimental.

The SSL/TLS standard gives you probably all what you need. The implementations had problems in the past and will probably have problems in the future. You might have a look at LibreSSL which is a fork of OpenSSL with lots of cruft and unnecessary features and also some weak security removed. NSS looks also like a solid library which had few serious problems in the past compared to OpenSSL, GnuTLS, SChannel and SecureTransport.

But note that SSL/TLS and also other encryption is not simple and you should make yourself comfortable with the concepts and pitfalls before you use it for serious code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Steffen Ullrich (above) i would add that just plain encryption is almost never a good solution, you also need:

1. Data integrity - encryption without it is vulnerable to bit flipping attacks
2. Authentication - even if you had the best possible encryption in the galaxy it would not help you much if you were talking to a wrong guy. E.g. if your connect to a server that pretends to be your bank - would it matter if the connection is encrypted or not ? You would give your credentials to this imposter!
3. Non-repudiation - is sometimes important too

In short: if you think that you can properly implement your own (over plain socket) enrypted connection (and you do not have a doctorate in the field :)) I would suggest to rethink the matter. Even if OpenSSL has/had some security issues - it is still orders of magnitude better than writing your own encrypted connection.

I hope that helps.